Noise goes away when I brake
What are the creek screech and clank sounds with my rear right breaks while I am driving that go away when I brake.
So back story. Last year we took a 12-13 hrs road trip to the mountains. About 3 or so hours into the drive our entire wheel came off and snapped off the wheel bolts where the lug nuts screw onto probably due to a loose lug nut. Thankfully despite the wheel breaking off it stayed In place. After this We spent a quite a few hours on our trip in and out of different mechanics between replacing the bolts and lug nuts to having multiple rancid sounds coming from the brake system. There was screeching, grinding, knocking, and other sounds. We replaced the brakes and rotors and bent back the  brake shield we tightened the calipers and made sure the lug nuts were good. We do get it to calm briefly but never get it to go away completely and comes back with a vengeance after a while. The sounds follows the circular motion and hits every rotation so it does speed up and slow down with the car I have also notice that most of the sounds disappear when I press on the brakes.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model of the vehicle in question?

2013 Chrysler town and country mini van

Usually, when a noise regarding brakes quits when you press on the brake pedal, this is an indication that the "squealer" is doing what it's supposed to do when the brake pad gets too thin. If you've replaced it recently, or it has continued to do the same thing after brake replacement, I'd suggest this isn't the case here.

We have replaced them.
